Matching control group and treatmeant group period in staggered difference-in-differences
I am investigating how different types of electoral systems systems Proportional Representation (PR) or Majoritarian System (MS). influence the level of clientelism in a country. I want to investigate this by exploiting a sort of natural experiment, where I investigate the level of clientelism in countries that have reformed - going from one electoral system to another. With a Difference-in-Difference design I  will examine their levels of clientelism just before and after reform to see if the change in electoral system has made a difference. By doing this I would expect to get (a clean as you can get) effect of the different systems on the level of clientelism.
My treatment group(s): countries that have undergone reform - grouped by type of reform, e.g. going from Proportional to Majoritarian and vice versa. My control group(s) are the countries that have never undergone reform. The control group(s) are matched according to the treatment groups. So:

Treatment Group 1: Countries going from Proportional Representation (PR) to Majoritarian System (MS)
is matched with:
Control Group 1: Countries that have Proportional Representation and have never undergone reform in their type of electoral system

The countries reformed at different times in history. This is solved with a staggered DiD design. The period displayed in my model is then the 20 years before reform and the 20 years after - the middle point is the year of treatment, "year 0".
But here comes my issue: My control group doesn't have an obvious "year 0" (year of reform) to sort them by like my treatment group does. How do I know which period to include for my control group? Pick the period that most of the treatment countries reformed? Do I use a matching-procedure, where I match each of my treatment countries with their most similar counter-part in that period?
I am really at a loss here, so your help is very much appreciated.

Why don't you use a method specifically designed for staggered adoption instead of trying to fit your data into a traditional matching or DiD analysis?
